# "free_y" facet_wrap equivalent in seaborn, python

Tags: python, r, nlp, seaborn

I want to do a plot showing sentiment split by most frequent words in tweets.
What I need is basically equivalent of scales='free_y' from R.

```
sns.catplot(x="count", y="word", col="emotion",
            data=df, kind="bar",
            height=4, aspect=.7, col_wrap=4)
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image: catplot]
I have one y axis and all words listed regardless of the emotion assigned, but I would like to have only the ones relevant to each group:

[image: like this]
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `sharex=True, sharey=True` by default

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments `sharex` and `sharey` in `catplot` control which axes will be shared among the plots, by default they are both set to `True`.